# Verificar tipo de separador em um arquivo CSV

Tags: php, mysql, csv, importação

Montei um *script* para importação de `CSV` com `PHP` mas estou tendo dificuldade com a verificação do tipo de formatação do `CSV`. Preciso verificar se ele é separado por `,`ou `;` ou `\t` ou `:` ou `|`, mas não estou conseguindo.

Segue o *Script*:

```
<?php

    $arquivo = isset($_FILES["file_csv"]) ? $_FILES["file_csv"] : FALSE;

    $tipoValido = "text/comma-separated-values";

    if($tipoValido != $arquivo["type"])
    {
        echo "Arquivo em formato inválido! O arquivo deve ser extensão CSV. Envie outro arquivo";
        echo '<br/><a href="index.html">Fazer Upload de Outro Arquivos</a>';
    }
    else
    {
        preg_match("/\.(csv){1}$/i", $arquivo["name"], $ext);

        $arquivo_nome = date("d-m-Y_H-i-s") . "." . $ext[1];

        move_uploaded_file($arquivo["tmp_name"], $arquivo_nome);

        $row = 0;
        $handle = fopen ($arquivo_nome,"r");
        echo "<table border=1>";
        while ( $data = fgetcsv ($handle, 1000, ",") )
        {
            $num = count ($data);
            $row++;


            $coluna1 = $data[0];
            $coluna2 = $data[1];
            $coluna3 = $data[2];
            $coluna4 = $data[3];
            $coluna5 = $data[4];

            //$query = "INSERT INTO tabela ( coluna1 , coluna2 , coluna3 ) VALUES ( '$coluna1' , '$coluna2' , '$coluna3', '$coluna4', '$coluna5' )";
            //mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

            if ($row != 1)
            {

                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$coluna1."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$coluna2."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$coluna3."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$coluna4."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$coluna5."</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        }

        echo "</table>";

        echo "<p>Dados da planilha inseridos com sucesso!<br/>Total de linhas inseridas: ".$row."</p>";

        fclose ($handle);

        unlink($arquivo_nome);
    }

?>
```

Comment: Tem 5 campos esse csv sempre?

Comment: @rray A ideia é esta, mas se ele for dinâmico seria até melhor.

Comment: Se você der um `explode` por algum desses delimitadores pode saber qual é o delimitador certo pois ele retorna um array com algum elemento

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consegui uma solução e vou deixar registrado aqui, caso alguém precise.

Criei uma ***função*** para verificar o delimitador do arquivo, segue o ***script*** completo com o leitor de `CSV`:

```
<?php

function getArquivoDelimitador($arquivo_recebido, $verificar_linhas = 2)
{
    $arquivo_recebido = new SplFileObject($arquivo_recebido);

    $delimitadores = array(',', "\t", ';', '|', ':');

    $resultado = array();

    for($i = 0; $i < $verificar_linhas; $i++){
        $linha = $arquivo_recebido->fgets();
        foreach ( $delimitadores as $delimitador )
        {
            $regExp = '/['.$delimitador.']/';

            $fields = preg_split( $regExp, $linha );

            if( count( $fields ) > 1 )
            {
                if( !empty( $resultado[$delimitador] ) )
                {
                    $resultado[$delimitador]++;
                } else {
                    $resultado[$delimitador] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $resultado = array_keys( $resultado, max( $resultado ) );

    return $resultado[0];
}

$arquivo = isset($_FILES["file_csv"]) ? $_FILES["file_csv"] : FALSE;

$delimitador = getArquivoDelimitador($arquivo['tmp_name']);

$tipoValido = "text/comma-separated-values";

if($tipoValido != $arquivo["type"])
{
    echo "Arquivo em formato inválido! O arquivo deve ser extensão CSV. Envie outro arquivo";
    echo '<br/><a href="index.html">Fazer Upload de Outro Arquivos</a>';
}
else
{
    preg_match("/\.(csv){1}$/i", $arquivo["name"], $ext);

    $arquivo_nome = date("d-m-Y_H-i-s") . "." . $ext[1];

    move_uploaded_file($arquivo["tmp_name"], $arquivo_nome);

    $row = 0;
    $handle = fopen ($arquivo_nome,"r");
    echo "<table border=1>";

    while ( $data = fgetcsv ($handle, 1000, $delimitador) )
    {
        $num = count ($data);
        $row++;


        $coluna1 = $data[0];
        $coluna2 = $data[1];
        $coluna3 = $data[2];
        $coluna4 = $data[3];
        $coluna5 = $data[4];

        //$query = "INSERT INTO tabela ( coluna1 , coluna2 , coluna3 ) VALUES ( '$coluna1' , '$coluna2' , '$coluna3', '$coluna4', '$coluna5' )";
        //mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

        if ($row != 1)
        {

            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$coluna1."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$coluna2."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$coluna3."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$coluna4."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$coluna5."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }

    echo "</table>";

    echo "<p>Dados da planilha inseridos com sucesso!<br/>Total de linhas inseridas: ".$row."</p>";

    fclose ($handle);

        unlink($arquivo_nome);
    }

?>
```

Comment: @ctgPi É, mas não é, por algum que desconheço quando é passado o paramento para `fgetcsv` com o retorno do `$resultado[0]` ela não entende. Acredito que na montagem dinâmica da variável ele se perde, mesmo concatenando `"` não funciona.

Comment: @ctgPi não entendi quando se refere a `'\t' != "\t"` em vários lugares, você poder me indicar de forma mais específica? Assim posso tentar melhor, claro se quiser editar para deixar o código melhor toda a ajuda é bem vinda

Comment: Funcionou, removi o `switch` e está retornando corretamente, também fiz a alteração do `<` no lugar de `<=`, obrigado. Sobre a leitura de um CSV pequeno o `for` está limitado para ler só as 2 primeiras linhas pela variável `$verificar_linhas`, mesmo assim acredita que iria dar problema?

Comment: Já ouviu falar da “Lei de Murphy”? :) Não precisa ser muito complicado, é só verificar se o `fgets` falhou e dar break nesse caso. Não sei se isso é código que você colocou só pra debugar, mas `echo "<td>".$coluna1."</td>";` precisa de `htmlspecialchars()` antes de concatenar.

Comment: Eu também sugiro que você leia [essa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3864/como-prevenir-inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-c%C3%B3digo-sql-no-meu-c%C3%B3digo-php/3869#3869).

Comment: Seria algo assim `if ($linha)
            {
             break;
             echo "Erro ao processar o arquivo";
             exit();
            }` ? Vou dar uma lida sim no link, já tinha pesquisado e vou começar a utilizar o `mysqli` obrigado.

Comment: Não nessa ordem porque o `break` garante que o resto do código não vai ser executado. :) Eu acho que a condição é `$linha === false` ou `$linha === FALSE`, mas não tenho certeza. Mas você não precisa chamar exit(); eu não posso querer importar um CSV de uma linha só? Ou a primeira linha é sempre o cabeçalho?

Comment: Utilizei o `!$linha` exatamente por que não sabia se era `false` ou `FALSE`, pensei que desta forma seria qualquer retorno `false`. Sobre o cabeçalho o correto é que sempre tenha, isso para orientar as colunas, mas vou remover aqui para que seja melhor sua reutilização.

Comment: `!$linha` não funciona; eu acabei de fazer [uma pergunta a respeito disso](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/69573/como-distinguir-false-da-string-vazia).

Comment: Vi que responderam sua pergunta mas será que tem diferença entre `FALSE` e `false` ?

Comment: Resolve meu problema, obrigado...

Answer (score 0):

No meu projeto Java, [uniVocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial), eu criei um algoritmo capaz de identificar:

- separator de valor (,)
- separador de linha
- aspas (duplas ou simples)
- escape de aspas (geralmente \" ou "")

[Veja aqui o algoritmo](https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers/blob/master/src/main/java/com/univocity/parsers/csv/CsvFormatDetector.java) (aviso: eh complexo). O processo nao eh simples pois voce tem que ignorar o que estiver entre aspas, valores com separator de linha, etc.

Nao deve ser muito dificil recriar esse codigo em PHP.